# Building a Dynamic Table in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dynamic-content

I am trying to build a table within Marketing Cloud, where I have three rows and 2 columns.

For all records, there will be a value in both columns of the first row, however, for some this will be it, some will have values in the first and second row only, and others will have values in all rows.

I only want the row of the table to display when there are values.

Is this something that can be built using dynamic content blocks, or does it require AMPScript?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with AMPScript.  Something like this:

```ampscript
<script runat="server" language="ampscript">

 var @r1c1, @r1c2, @r2c1, @r2c2, @r3c1, @r3c2
 set @r1c1 = "r1c1"
 set @r1c2 = "r1c2"
 set @r2c1 = "r2c1"
 set @r3c2 = "r3c2"
 set @r3c1 = "r3c1"
 set @r3c2 = "r3c2"

</script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>%%=v(@r1c1)=%%</td>
        <td>%%=v(@r1c2)=%%</td>
    </tr>

    %%[ if not empty(@r2c1) or not empty(@r2c2) then ]%%
    <tr>
        <td>%%=v(@r2c1)=%%</td>
        <td>%%=v(@r2c2)=%%</td>
    </tr>
    %%[ endif ]%%    

    %%[ if not empty(@r3c1) or not empty(@r3c2) then ]%%
    <tr>
        <td>%%=v(@r3c1)=%%</td>
        <td>%%=v(@r3c2)=%%</td>
    </tr>
    %%[ endif ]%%  

</table>
```

**Reference**

- [**if**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm#using-if-syntax)
- [**empty()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/empty.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use either. HTML will not render a row if there is no content in its cells. I think this may only apply where the table has 0 cellpadding and cellspacing. Try this:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>1. This row will be displayed.</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>2. This row will be displayed.</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
        <td><!-- 3. This row will not be displayed. --></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4. This row will</td>
        <td>be displayed.</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

[image]